# Why does JSLint returns 'bad escapement' on this line of code?

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

Why is it that JSLint returns a 'Bad escapement' on the following JavaScript line ?

```
param = param.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
```

From JSLint documentation I thought that this would be ok since the regex literal is preceeded by a parenthesis:

> Regular expressions are written in a
>   terse and cryptic notation. JSLint 
>   looks for problems that may cause
>   portability problems. It also attempts
>   to resolve visual ambiguities by
>   recommending explicit escapement.
>
> JavaScript's syntax for regular
>   expression literals overloads the /
>   character. To avoid ambiguity, JSLint
>   expects that the character preceding a
>   regular expression literal is a ( or =
>   or : or , character.

Comment: Why are you using character classes for single characters?

Comment: Are you sure that "Bad escapement" refers to the character preceding a regular expression? The error message and your quoted description don't seem to match.

Comment: @Johannes: It doesn't refer to the regular expressions, but I can see how one could think that. It's the only section in the instructions where "escapement" is mentioned.

Comment: @Anon - As I mentioned in my comments to Guffa's answer, my regex skills are just plain terrible, add in the escaping and I was lost. I do get it now though. @Johannes - Guffa explained exactly what happened, I looked at JSLint's documentation and that's the only place I found where 'escapement' was mentionned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not the regular expression that it's complaining about. You are escaping characters in the replacement strings that doesn't need escaping at all.

The [ and ] characters have no special meaning in an ordinary string, you don't have to escape them:

```
param = param.replace(/[\[]/,"\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\]");
```

Note: As Anon pointed out, you don't need to use a character set for a single character:

```
param = param.replace(/\[/,"\\[").replace(/\]/,"\\]");
```

You can also match both characters in a single regular expression, catch what you match and use in the replacement. If you want to replace more than the first occurance, you want to use the global option:

```
param = param.replace(/(\[|\])/g,"\\$1");
```

Comment: Thx Guffa. I was about to update as after playingn around with it a bit more I figured out that I had an extra escape in there. My regex skills are terrible, this is part of a 'querystring' function I found on some website to retrieve parameters from the URL so I hadn't questionned it much as it was working. I see your one line version is much better though, thx!